# ng-repeat is repeating multiple time with same array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

ng-repeat is binding same array with multiple times.

js :

```
    $scope.currentitem = item;
    $scope.currentitemCategory = $scope.currentitem.category.split(',');
    console.log($scope.currentitemCategory);
```

html:

```
   <div ng-repeat="category in currentitemCategory track by $index">
             <a href="/content/digital-library/us/en/search.html?category={{category}}">
            <span class="text"> {{category}} </span>
            </a>
                                         </div>
```

console :

Categorized in 
                                            
                                                
                                                     [audience/business](/content/digital-library/us/en/search.html?category=audience/business) 
                                                
                                             
                                                
                                                     [audience/business](/content/digital-library/us/en/search.html?category=audience/business) 
                                                
                                             
                                                
                                                     [audience/business](/content/digital-library/us/en/search.html?category=audience/business) 
                                                
                                             
                                                
                                                     [brandguidelines](/content/digital-library/us/en/search.html?category=brandguidelines) 
                                                
                                             
                                                
                                                     [brandguidelines](/content/digital-library/us/en/search.html?category=brandguidelines) 
                                                
                                             
                                                
                                                     [brandguidelines](/content/digital-library/us/en/search.html?category=brandguidelines) 
                                                
                                             
                                                
                                                     [corporateinitiatives/idf](/content/digital-library/us/en/search.html?category=corporateinitiatives/idf) 
                                                
                                             
                                                
                                                     [corporateinitiatives/idf](/content/digital-library/us/en/search.html?category=corporateinitiatives/idf) 
                                                
                                             
                                                
                                                     [corporateinitiatives/idf](/content/digital-library/us/en/search.html?category=corporateinitiatives/idf)

Comment: Please create a [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can you show us your jsfiddle to understand the exact problem?

Answer (score 1):

I've created a sample application with your given snippet. I do not see any repeated entries. Everything works fine. Please provide few more details if the issue really exists.

```js
var app= angular.module('sample', []);

app.controller('samplecontroller', function($scope){
   var item = {category: 'Tennis, Carroms, Soccer, Volleyball'};
   $scope.currentitem = item;
   $scope.currentitemCategory = $scope.currentitem.category.split(',');
   console.log($scope.currentitemCategory);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="sample">
  <div ng-controller="samplecontroller">
    <div ng-repeat="category in currentitemCategory track by $index">
      <a href="/content/digital-library/us/en/search.html?category={{category}}">
        <span class="text"> {{category}} </span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```